# Creating columns out of pipe delimited csv

Tags: bash, csv, pipe

I have a .csv file that all the data in a single column and within that data, it is all pipe delimited.

Currently:

```
COLUMN A  
info|info2|info3
```

What bash command could I use to break into a column for each? The top row contains the headers.

Example:

```
COLUMN A, COLUMN B, COLUMN C  
info, info2, info3
```

Comment: Are the headers also pipe delimited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are allowed to hard-code column headers, use this code:

```
echo "COLUMN A, COLUMN B, COLUMN C" > out.csv && sed -e '1d;s/|/, /g' in.csv >> out.csv
```

Example:

```
$ cat in.csv 
COLUMN A
info|info2|info3
$ echo "COLUMN A, COLUMN B, COLUMN C" > out.csv && sed -e '1d;s/|/, /g' in.csv >> out.csv
$ cat out.csv
COLUMN A, COLUMN B, COLUMN C
info, info2, info3
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

You could also try it in awk-

If your headers are already in csv format-

```
awk -F "|" 'NR==1 { print $0} ; NR > 1 {print $1","$2","$3}' file.txt
```

For the first line (NR==1), it prints out the whole line and for the rest it makes it comma separated.

If your headers are also pipe delimited then it is easier-

```
awk -F "|" ' {print $1","$2","$3}' file.txt
```